# Running client and server on different machine

Tags: node.js, server, client, ethernet

i have `client.js` and `server.js` that already being set up and working perfectly. Only issue right now, is that i need to run client on 1 machine, server on another machine.

However, through the use of ***ethernet*** cable connection, only `server.js` can be run. Client side is unable to connect even though both are able to ping each other's IP address.

Any solution I can look into? Much appreciated!

Do note that this will be run on virtual box ubuntu. For example, PC 1 will be running `server.js` on virtualbox ubuntu, PC 2 will be running `client.js` on virtual box ubuntu. However, after running `server.js`, `client.js` does not start/load.

Comment: are your IPs correct?

Comment: Yes, i have tested it. We are able to ping each other! Kindly assist @Roljhon

Answer (score 1):

When you run client and server on the same machine then you can use `localhost` hostname or an IP of 127.0.0.1 to connect via something that's called a loopback interface which is basically a virtual network card that routes everything back to itself.

When those are on different machines you need to use a real IP or hostname so you need to update your code or configuration to access the correct IP or port.

Also the port can be blocked by a firewall from external connections which is rarely done for `localhost`. You need to also make sure that your port is not blocked.

Of course only a very general answer can be given to a question that doesn't include:

- error message
- IP addresses and ports used
- protocol used
- source code

A general advice would be to:

1. Check your IPs
2. Check your firewalls

Ping uses an ICMP protocol so it is possible to have a connection with ping but not with TCP which I assume you are using (but again, you didn't specify that). And of course you are never sure which machine you're pinging, only that you got an answer so it is theoretically possible that you are pinging yourself. You need to get the right IPs.

To know the IP address on your server see those answers:

- [Finding external IP address](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22615/how-can-i-get-my-external-ip-address-in-a-shell-script/194136#194136)
- [Finding internal IP address](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430853/how-do-i-find-my-internal-ip-address/604691#604691)

Comment: Will this work as i am using virtual box to run both server and client, however both on different pc. For example, pc 1 will be running server.js on virtual box ubuntu, pc 2 will be running client.js on virtual box ubuntu.

Comment: @Marcus does this fixes your issue?

Comment: I have found out that the port that i am working on is open and not blocked. I have also ensure that the firewall allows the port from the incoming IP address. However, the issue still remains the same, which PC 2 cannot be connected to PC 1. PC 1 is running the server.js, PC2 is running client.js. Client.js is not working/running together with server.js